# Are compound arithmetic expressions possible in bash?

Tags: bash, math, expression

I want to test if (x/10)%2 == 1. But I'm getting errors when I do:

```
if (( (x/10)%2 )); then
  #blah
else
  #blah
fi
```

Is it possible? Or should I instead do something like:

```
y=((x/10))
z=((y%2))
if [[ z -eq 1 ]]; then
  #blah blah blah
```

Any insights?

Comment: You can do whatever you need in `((...))`. E.g. `(( (x/10)%2 ))` is fine. (you may want to include a specific test though `(( (x/10)%2 > 0 ))` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shucks, found an answer a minute after posting... as @David C. Rankin said in the comments above, I *can* do whatever I want inside the double (( and )). The errors I was getting was from something else that is missing from the above code because I simplified it for the question...

Anyways, while you're here, a tip re: arithmetic expansion (and the cause of my *actual* error...):

if you're going to assign a variable to the result of a (( ... )) expression, use this:

```
x=$(( (y/10)%2 ));
```

note the $ above- that will actually output the decimal number rather than just be a return code...